# Processing code not refreshing?

Tags: csv, arduino, processing

I'm new to Processing and I'm trying a simple code to test a light to frequency converter. I have recorded data onto a cvs file through an Arduino and I'm now looking to get Processing to read through the table and spew out (in text) the time and frequency per second.
However, it just seems to display them all at the same time? I do not know what I am doing wrong as the code works for print/println, but not on the screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```java
Table table;
TableRow row;
int fData;
String [] frequency;
String [] time;
int index = 0;

void setup() {
  size(800, 500);
  background(255);
  table = loadTable("test2.csv", "header");
  time = table.getStringColumn(1);
  frequency = table.getStringColumn(2);

  println(table.getColumnCount() + " columns in table"); 
  println(table.getRowCount() + " rows in table"); 
  println("Date: " + table.getString(1, 0)); 
  println("Start time: " + table.getString(0, 1));
  println("Duration: " + (table.getRowCount()/60) + " minutes"); 
}

void draw () {
  background(255); 
  text("Date: "+table.getString(0, 0), 30, 340);
  text("Start time: "+ time[index], 30, 360);
  fill(0); 


  for (int i = 0; i < 1575; i = i+1) {
    fData=((table.getInt(i, 2))/1000);// alpha range 0-255
    println(fData);

    fill(0);
    text("End time: " + time[i], 30, 380);
    text("Times:["+table.getString(i, 1)+"]", 30, 420);  
    fill(255);
    rect(0, height-100, width, 100);
    fill(0);

    text("fData:["+fData+"]", 30, 440);
    float number = +table.getInt(i, 2);
    println(number);

    text("#["+number+"]", 30, 480);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `text()` function takes 3 parameters: the `String` you want to display, and the `x` and `y` coordinates of the position it should be displayed.

Notice that you're always passing the same `x` and `y` values into the `text()` function, so you end up drawing everything in the same position.

You have to modify the `x` and/or `y` passed into the `text()` function. How you do that depends on exactly what you want to happen. But you'd probably start by modifying the position based on the for loop variable:

```
text("End time: " + time[i], 30, i*30);
```

Notice that here I'm changing the `y` value so that each iteration of the loop shows the text 30 pixels lower. That's just an example, but the idea is the same: you want to pass in different positions over time.

You could also do something like only displaying one line of text at a time, maybe for 1 second or so.

Here's an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your problem without all your extra code:

```
background(0);
String one = "ABC";
String two = "XYZ";
text(one, 25, 25);
text(two, 25, 25);
```

Since we're drawing the `one` and `two` `Strings` in the same location, we get this:

[image]

But we can change the positions we're passing in:

```
background(0);
String one = "ABC";
String two = "XYZ";
text(one, 25, 25);
text(two, 25, 50);
```

So now they draw in different locations:

[image]

If you have further questions, try to post your own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that uses hard-coded values instead of your entire sketch.

Comment: Thanks. I posted all the code since I did not know where the problem was. However, I want the text to display on the same line, like a counter.